# JavaFx TableView issues with big data

Tags: javafx-2, tableview, javafx

I have been using JavaFx's tableview to display a huge amount of data from the database. The table is like 150+ columns and millions of rows. I can handle the rows by getting the data in chunks and implementing paginations([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068907/javafx-tableview-performance-issue)). But the no of columns is also an area of concern. It takes a lot of time to paint the data and does not update the data when I change the values in the model([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065140/javafx-2-1-tableview-refresh-items/12737209#12737209)). I dont have a predefined data structure and so the method at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873361/javafx-tableview-is-not-updating%20will%20not%20work) is not useful. I moved on to use JTable inside JavaFx but JFX2.0 has removed the support for Swing components inside a JavaFX scene. So being left with tableview is there some way to add pagination to columns and rows both without overutlizing the memory ?

Comment: You may think of splitting table into several groups stored on few tabs. It's a bit hard to imagine a user able to work with data from from 150 columns.

Comment: JTable is able to handle and is pretty quick in displaying and updating the data with 150+ cols, whereas TableView is not able to match up. Is there some way to disable some options that might be enabled in javafx.TableView by default to speed things up ?