# JavaFx TableView big data(20000 rows)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm using JavaFx 2.0  TableView to display big data.

The problem is when i fill the TableView with 20,000 rows, it's became too slowly to display and search in the TableView, and it's take around 12 seconds to display the data into the TableView, also there are no obstacles from Database engine party.

I did a research for the possibility to solve it and how i can improve the performance of that TableView.

Can anyone help me for this issue ?!?

Comment: here is a related question which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197490/javafx-tableview-issues-with-big-data

Comment: It should work fine. I've tested `TableView`s with up to two million rows with no performance issues (on a machine with enough memory to hold the data). If you're experiencing performance problems there's probably something wrong with your code. Create and post a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Do you use Linux? Does your table contain mostly (or only) text in an RTL language (such as Arabic, Farsi or Hebrew) or another complex script (such as Hindi, Devanagari etc.)?

Comment: you can use pagination JavaFX .